# FTDI Driver for Custom PID and VID

Tags: process, software-installation, usb, udev, modprobe

I have changed VID and PID of my ftdi board to 0001 and 0002.
Now the com is not showing and the device is showing in unknown device.

How can make a customize driver for it to get com port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, the following should work without requiring a new driver:

```
sudo modprobe ftdi-sio vendor=0x0001 product=0x0002
```

Comment: Sir it is working on linux but i am a windows user and i am still looking for solution.

Comment: I have edit fdtibus and fdtiport .inf file in order to customize the driver but i forcefully installed the driver to windows because of device signature problem.

Comment: @AmanSrivastav this isn't a Windows site...

Comment: Sorry Sir What i really want a customize name of COM port for that all this i am doing. Is there any other way on ubntu to customize the port name?